# Using json as column name in cassandra table does not work after cassandra upgrade

Tags: json, database, cassandra, insert, upgrade

Recently there was a driver upgrade for Cassandra from 2.0.4 to 3.1.0 in my project. I found that the insert statement does not work on the tables that has 'json' as column name. The same insert statement used to work on previous cassandra version.

Sample insert statement:

insert into table_name (name, id, json) values ("AAA", "123", '{"display-order":"1","product-id":"QWERTY"}');

When I tried the query in Datastax DevCenter, I am getting the error as "**no viable alternative at input 'json'**"

Does that mean that we have to change the insert statements?

Please help!

**Edit:**
I made a mistake in the example query, json type is not the issue. When I enabled debug I found that the issue is with timestamp column. 
I did not mention that in my example as I thought json could be the reason.

This is because of the recent driver update to 3.1.0, as the same query does not work now.
When I tried to fix it, I could not find the timestamp converter function (toTimestamp) or the dateOf() function in 3.1.0 version.
I see only now() but it returns only of type timeuuid.

Is there any other way I can convert the current date to timestamp?

Answer (score 0):

It's not because of json field, your insert format is not correct

Use string as enclosed with single quote :

```
cassandra@cqlsh:test> insert into test_json  (name, id, json) values ('AAA', '123', '{"display-order":"1","product-id":"QWERTY"}');

cassandra@cqlsh:test> SELECT * FROM test_json ;

 id  | json                                        | name
-----+---------------------------------------------+------
 123 | {"display-order":"1","product-id":"QWERTY"} |  AAA
```

Or Double dollar signs to enclose a string with quotes, backslashes, or other characters that would normally need to be escaped

```
cassandra@cqlsh:test> insert into test_json  (name, id, json) values ('AAA', '123', $${"display-order":"1","product-id":"QWERTY"}$$);
cassandra@cqlsh:test> SELECT * FROM test_json ;

 id  | json                                        | name
-----+---------------------------------------------+------
 123 | {"display-order":"1","product-id":"QWERTY"} |  AAA
```

By the way, if you want to insert current timestamp use `dateof(now())` or if you use java use `new Date()`

Comment: Thanks @Ashraful for the reply. Please find my edit in the original question.

Comment: @ek_cool if you want to insert current timestamp use dateof(now()) or if you use java use new Date()